# Using multiples alarms

Tags: java, android, alarm

I want to use alarms to trigger some processing.

In the code below, I have tried to set two alarms. They trigger a `Service` which displays a `Notification` indicating the id number of the alarm which has just gone off.

When the first `Alarm` goes off, a `Notification` should appear and display : "1".
For the second `Alarm`, the `Notification` should show "2".

As described in the Javadoc, only one alarm is triggered (they have the same `Intent`, so the second one replaces the first one). But what is strange is that the `Notification` displays "1" and appears at the time when the second `Alarm` goes off!!! It seems that the time for the alarm to go off is modified but not the extras.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance for the time you will spend trying to help me.

```
public class TestAlarmes extends Activity{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    AlarmManager am;
    Intent action;
    PendingIntent intent;
    long t0;
    RecepteurMessageAlarme récepteur;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // créer le récepteur de message d'alarme
    récepteur=new RecepteurMessageAlarme();

    // et l'enregistrer en lui demandant de filtrer sur les messages d'alarme
    registerReceiver(récepteur,new IntentFilter("GL.TestAlarmes.ALARME"));

    // récupérer le service d'alarme
    am=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    // créer l'action 1
    action=new Intent(this,ServiceAlarme.class);
    action.setAction("GL.TestAlarmes.ALARME");

    // personnaliser l'action a exécuter
    action.putExtra("GL.TestAlarmes.Action",1);

    // créer l'intent à lancer lors du déclenchement de l'alarme
    intent=PendingIntent.getService(this,0,action,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    // prendre l'instant présent
    t0=java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis();

    // configurer l'alarme
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,t0+5000,intent);

    // créer l'action 2
    action=new Intent(this,ServiceAlarme.class);
    action.setAction("GL.TestAlarmes.ALARME");

    // personnaliser l'action a exécuter
    action.putExtra("GL.TestAlarmes.Action",2);

    // créer l'intent à lancer lors du déclenchement de l'alarme
    intent=PendingIntent.getService(this,0,action,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    // configurer l'alarme
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,t0+10000,intent);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving different request codes for `PendingIntent` to make it unique